# Can an Html.Actionlink pass the selected value of a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC razor page where I have two HTML action links which work fine separately, but not together. Before looking into a jQuery option, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. I was hoping I could keep things simple by adding a second parameter to the relevant html.actionlink.

I am making the transition from Web Pages to MVC, so I gathered what I have so far by looking at examples on the Microsoft ASP.NET learning resources and other SO posts.

These are the current (relevant) sections of my cshtml page.

**First action (filter by dropdown):** At the top of the page I have a dropdown by which I can filter the form by one column value. By itself, it works great.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <p>
    Filter by Campus: @Html.DropDownList("searchByFilter", new SelectList(ViewBag.names)) 
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
  </p>
}
```

**Second Action (sort by column):** In the header row of the table, I have an action link, where when a user clicks the column header, the controller serves the table sorted appropriately. I'm just showing a single column out of the table to show you how it works.

```
<th>                        
   @Html.ActionLink("Campus", "Index", new { orderBy = ViewBag.CampusSortParm })       
</th>
```

**The problem:**  While these work great independently -- for obvious reasons, the two action links don't work together. I was hoping I could keep things simple and do something like this, adding a second parameter which can read the value of the dropdown (null is not an option).

```
<th>                        
   @Html.ActionLink("Campus", "Index", new { orderBy = ViewBag.CampusSortParm 
   @*, searchByFilter = selected value of searchByFilter dropdown, but how do I get it here? *@  })
</th>
```

Can I add a second parameter in this fashion, or do I need to look into a jQuery solution?

Comment: You need javascript/jquery. `@Html.ActionLink()` is razor code that is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. It cannot respond to client side events.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that, but I wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stephen Muecke for confirming that the question I posed needed to be done in jQuery or Javascript.

However, after asking myself why my code was able to work so far, I thought of an obvious change I could make. Rather than sorting by column click, I simply make it part of the form submission.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <p>
        Filter by Campus: @Html.DropDownList("searchBy", new SelectList(ViewBag.names))
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Sort by Column: </strong>
        @Html.DropDownList("orderBy", new SelectList (ViewBag.SortByColumns))
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Sort Direction: </strong>            
        @Html.DropDownList("orderDir", new SelectList(ViewBag.SortDir))
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</div>
}
```

This works perfectly now for my needs. The result of my question is achieved.